# python : `moduleNotFoundError` when attempting to import file from a directory

Tags: python

Running into `moduleNotFoundError` when attempting to import a file from root directory.

Directory structure for Flask App:

```
index.py
auth_
  - server.py
Pages
  - home.py
```

I am able to import `home.py` from `Pages`, but not `server.py` from `auth_`

In `index.py`, I am attempting to import `server.py`

```
from auth_ import server


File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'auth_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 338, in __call__
    self._flush_bg_loading_exception()
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 326, in _flush_bg_loading_exception
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 314, in _load_app
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 330, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 388, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
  File "/Users/xxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 250, in locate_app
    raise NoAppException('Could not import "{name}".'.format(name=module_name))
flask.cli.NoAppException: Could not import "auth_".
```

Comment: `from .auth_ import server`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from .auth_ import server
```

will solve your problem.

`.` means the current directory in which you run your script, i.e. `index.py`, so with `.auth_` you have `auth_` folder in the same directory with `index.py` and you want to call a file or folder in `auth` directory.

Final statement (`from .auth_ import server`) tells that you will use `server.py` script, which is located in `auth_` folder and `auth_` folder is in the same directory with your `index.py`.

I recommend you to look at [this guide](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/) to understand absolute and relative imports in Python.

Comment: from .auth_ import server
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: Then you should include parent directory. `from parent_package.auth_ import server `  where `parent_package` is the parent directory of index.py, auth_ and Pages.